# context regex split

Tags: python, regex, split

I want to split a string on `', '` but not on `',, '`

So with input `'abc,, def, ghi'` I want output

`[ 'abc,, def', 'ghi' ]`

I tried `re.split("(?:[^,]), ",'abc,, def, ghi' )`
but it removed the `'f'`

is there a way to do this?

Comment: I just found `"(?<=[^,]), "`  perhaps I should delete this question

Comment: Nah, feel free to post your own answer if you don't like mine.

Comment: Actually, `'(?<=[^,]), '`  is not equal to `'(?<!,), '` as the latter also matches  a comma+space at the start of the string.

Comment: that's a good point.  I didn't explicitly say it by my lists have no empty entries.

Comment: You can try something like [`(?<!,),(?!\s*,)\s*`](https://regex101.com/r/RtL1f0/2) OR if you just want to split by a comma-followed-by-a-space, you can modify it to [`(?<!,),(?!\s*,)\s+`](https://regex101.com/r/RtL1f0/4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend using regex lookarounds:

```
>>> re.split('(?<!,),(?=\s)', text)
['abc,, def', ' ghi']
```

**Details**

```
(?<!   # negative lookbehind
,      # comma
)
,      
(?=    # positive lookahead
\s     # whitespace
)
```

Semantically, this means "split on a single comma *only* (comma that is not preceded or succeeded by any commas)."

Comment: actuallY I want to split on comma-space but my in my original post the spaces got eaten by the html rendering. I can replace the lookahead with a space and get what I want.

Comment: @Jasen Edited, ty.

Comment: my problem was finding lookbehind, I can't explain how I missed that section of the docs.

Comment: I recommend you to change the regex to: re.split('(?<!,),(?!,)', text) , it's more general ..

Comment: @Minion wait, that's what it was, until op said that's not what they wanted... hah

Comment: The anwer was close enough to perfect to be useful.and still is.